# How can I merge the different keyboard indicators?

Tags: indicator, keyboard-layout, ibus, input-method

Presently I use two application indicators showing a keyboard:

- input methods (iBus)
- keyboard layout

Is there a way to make them merge into one single indicator icon ? What I have in mind is the equivalent of the messaging menu (gathering all that is related to communications) or the sound menu (gathering all the controls for sound).

If it is too complicated to merge the indicators, is the merge planned for an upcoming Ubuntu release?

I am on Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity as my environment.

Comment: Right, it's annoying to have a separate icon for Japanese (ibus) and for two other Western languages (keyboard layout indicator, whatever).

Comment: Would it be okay with you if I just told you how to get rid of one? If so, which one would you prefer to hide? Which desktop environment are you using, and which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Thank you William but no, it wouldn't be okay. I edited my question to explain that I want to use both indicators.

Comment: I've never looked into it, but I feel like it wouldn't be hard to write an indicator that simply brings the two others up when it is clicked on (in a submenu). I'm assuming you're just bothered by having two icons and not by the fact that they're separate workflows. There is some same C code here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Typical_usage_.28C_version.29

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I do not think this is an AskUbuntu question as it would require a developer to implement a solution. A more appropriate place to ask would be the [Brainstorm site](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) is